# First field autofocus when invalid error occur - reactive form

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular4-forms

when i forgot to fill some field and submit form button then i go manually scroll-up in small device for find required field. so i want to autofocus that particular field on submit. i'm done lots of R&D. please guide me

i try with this code but not work

```
if (!this.form.valid) {
 let invalid = <FormControl[]>Object.keys(this.form.controls).map(key => this.form.controls[key]).filter(ctl => ctl.invalid);
  if (invalid.length > 0) {
    invalid[0].nativeElement.focus();
   //here i'm not find any nativeElement
  }  
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Give some code you have tried , And also please provide the error log !!

Comment: thanks @PiashSarker my app is running well and good and  don't have any error but i try to add this type of functionality

Comment: In which input you want to add autofocus.  Add tge input html.

Comment: some of input i have used in my form like ion-search, input ,radio , ion-select etc